How to check consistency of a generated web site using recursive HTML parsing
I have a FOSS project whose web site is generated by asciidoc and some custom scripts as an horde (thousands) of static files locally in the source files' repo, copied into another workspace and uploaded to github.io style repository, and eventually is rendered as an HTTP server for browsers around the world to see.
Users occasionally report that some of the links between site pages end up broken (lead nowhere).
The website build platform is generally POSIX-ish, although most often the agent doing the regular work is a Debian/Linux one. Maybe the platform differences cause the "page outages"; maybe this bug is platform-independent.
I had a thought about crafting a check for the two local directories as well as the resulting site to crawl all relative links (and/or absolute ones starting with its domain name(s)), and report any broken pages so I could focus on finding why they fail and/or avoiding publication of "bad" iterations - same as with compilers, debuggers and warnings elsewhere.
The general train of thought is about using some wget spider mode, though any other command-line tool (curl, lynx...), python script, shell with sed, etc. would do as well. Surely this particular wheel has been invented too many times for me to even think about making my own? A quick and cursory googling session while on commute did not come up with any good fit however.
So, suggestions are welcome :)

Any Javascript/dynamic content in those pages or is that just only <a href="relative/path/only"> (and no <base href="...">)? Is it just links you want to check or also the <img src="..."> and other embedded content?

https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer sounds relevant (packaged in Debian in ruby-html-proofer)

Thanks a lot @StéphaneChazelas - it does at least report a few hundred issues, inside the site and outside it (with third-party pages we refer to), so definitely something for me to chew on :)

Please feel free to answer your own question with how you used it to address your question. I'm not planning to answer myself.

Thanks, for now I'll pursue this at https://github.com/networkupstools/nut-website/issues/52 eventually, and hope to summarize what comes of it. So far the idea is to extend the configure.ac and Makefile.am to detect presence of the tool in PATH and optionally call it as some make check-something target generally, or have a separate stage in CI recipe for calling that (depending on whether I would be able to obliterate ALL issues I can, and avoid reporting errors on e.g. external sites - so they would not block builds/publication of ours).

As suggested in the comments, the htmlproofer tool from GitHub (or ruby-html-proofer Debian/Ubuntu package) seems like a relevant solution to the problem, or at the very least a very decent first step.
Fixes relevant to the project in question can be seen at this PR and involve documentation how to install the tool, a configure.ac detection of it in PATH or as provided by the user/caller, and some Makefile.am recipes to call it for the locations involved in the website build with options which make sense to the project (or can be overruled by caller of the make program).
Performance is highly variable, from several minutes on a cloud build agent to about 40 minutes on a laptop. Initially there was some hit taken from network queries involved in external link checking by default (and almost 2000 such links to crawl), but the --disable_external option should supposedly take care of that (at least, netstat -an does not display any lingering connections during a re-run).
